# React Native activity class does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.fish"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.12.+'
}
```

I tried many ways to fix this, but nothing seems to work. Maybe somebody got this error, too. I'm using node stable (4.0.0).

Yesterday it worked(the app was opening with a white screen, but still it worked) but i don't know what happened meanwhile.

L.e.: Sorry, i forgot to write the error :)

```
Starting the app (/Users/matei/Library/Android/sdk//platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.fish/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.fish/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.fish/com.fish.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

I'm new to react native and I don't know what to do.

L.e. 2: The project is the init one from react-native android command. Nothing added.

Comment: Are you able to upload the project to GitHub so we could check out all the files? That would help out a lot.

Comment: hey , did you solve it?

Comment: @Matei, did you solve this ever?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that there is nothing wrong with your AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle files, run the follow command on terminal:

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent a day for this problem.

Finally, I solved it.

If You have facing this problem, check the application has removed completely.

You could go to Settings menu and go to Apps and check that application was removed.